# why doesn't HAProxy support "option redispatch" in tcp mode?

Tags: tcp, haproxy

in HTTP mode, if "option redispatch" is set, HAProxy will automatic retry another backend if current one is down. the whole process is transparent seen from the client, expect the response time would be longer than normal situation.

i wondering why this option is supported in TCP mode? theoretically, it should possible.

Comment: I was able to enable it on a TCP-mode listener. Did you try it? Are you sure retries is set greater than zero?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way HTTP sessions work. The session token is stored inside a HTTP cookie. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)#HTTP_session_token):

> A session token is a unique identifier that is generated and sent from a server to a client to identify the current interaction session. The client usually stores and sends the token as an HTTP cookie and/or sends it as a parameter in GET or POST queries.

As a result, HAProxy can not read/manipulate session information in TCP mode as it must first open the HTTP connection to read the cookie data. If HAProxy can not read session information then it would have no way of knowing whether or not the client is trying to connect to a dead server, and as a result, whether it should attempt to reallocate it.

This is backed up in the [HAProxy configuration manual](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-option%20redispatch) for `option redispatch`.

Comment: thanks, @JamesStewy. but i think if the user specify TCP mode, HAPROXY will not consider HTTP cookies anyway, right?

Comment: That's correct. And as a result, HAProxy can't read HTTP session information which makes `option redispatch` redundant.